# Why is $\operatorname{Var}[X]≤(b−a)^2/4$ if $X$ is a random variable with values between $[a,b]$

Tags: probability, variance

I don't know how to start here. I tried to proof it with $$\operatorname{Var}(X) =  E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2$$ but this wasn't a good idea in the end.

Comment: What are b, a, and do we know anything about X?  (For example, X can be a distribution that doesn't have a variance defined.)

Comment: X is a random variable with values between [a,b]

Comment: you have to speficy the distribution of $X$

Comment: Side note: this is [Popoviciu's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popoviciu%27s_inequality_on_variances).

Answer (score 16):

Let $Y$=$X-\frac{a+b}{2}$.  Since they differ by a constant, $\operatorname{Var}(Y)=\operatorname{Var}(X)$.  Since $|Y|$ is always less than or equal to $|\frac{b-a}{2}|$, we have $Y^2$ is always less than $\frac{(b-a)^2}{4}$.  Thus $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\operatorname{Var}(Y)=E(Y^2)-(EY)^2\le E(Y^2)\le \frac{(b-a)^2}{4}$.  QED

Comment: You are genious!

Comment: Clean and nice.

Comment: Thank you very much can you also tell me for which Probability measure the equation is equals?

Comment: can you explain why $|Y|$ is always less then $\frac{|b-a|}{|2|}$?

Comment: $X\le b$ implies $Y=X-\frac{a+b}{2} \le b - \frac{a+b}{2} = \frac{b-a}{2} \le |\frac{b-a}{2}|$.   Also $X\ge a$ implies $Y=X-\frac{a+b}{2} \ge a - \frac{a+b}{2}  = \frac{a-b}{2} \ge -|\frac{a-b}{2}| =-|\frac{b-a}{2}|$.  Combining these shows $|Y|\le |\frac{b-a}{2}|$.

Comment: Equality can hold only if $X$ is $a$ with probability $1/2$ and $b$ with probability $1/2$.  First, if $X$ can take on any other value with positive probability, then $|Y|<|\frac{b-a}{2}|$ with positive probability, which forces $E(Y^2)$ and thus $Var(X)$ to be less than $\frac{(b-a)^2}{4}$.  If $X$ is supported on $\{a,b\}$ but with probabilities $p$ and $1-p$ you show by direct computation that $Var(X)$ is $\frac{(b-a)^2}{4}$. only for $p=1/2$.

Comment: so it's Bernoulli distribution

Comment: A random variable attaining the bound is a linear function of a Bernoulli(1/2).  Bernoulli random variables only take values $0$ and $1$, remember!.  :)

Comment: To be specific, it's $a+(b-a)Bernoulli(1/2)$

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself how you would distribute probability mass on the interval $[a,b]$ so as to make the probability mass as much "spread out" as possible. Intuitively, variance measures the "spread-out-ness" of a random variable (or distribution). It should be clear that if some probability mass is inside the interval (in $(a,b)$) then you can increase the spread by moving some of it against $a$, and some against $b$. So, for the maximum all mass should be at the interval ends $a$, $b$.

So assume that $\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}} \P(X=a)=p, \P(X=b)=1-p$, the you can calculate that the variance of $X$ is
$$
   p(1-p)(b^2-a^2)
$$
and by maximizing that in $p$ you will get your result.

Comment: The last line should be $p(1-p)(b-a)^2$

Answer (score -1):

If X has a uniform distribution $\mathcal{U}([a,b])$ then

\begin{equation}
var(X) = \frac{(b-a)^{2}}{12} \leq \frac{(b-a)^{2}}{4}
\end{equation}

Comment: It's also true if the distribution of $X$ is discrete with $1/2$ weight at $a$ and $b$ (and the bound is attained - intuitively it's the distribution with maximum variance given the constraint). The interesting part is proving this for *any* probability distribution.